# Un-link Integration Account from Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am not finding anything in the Azure Portal UI to un-link a previously associated Integration Account. I have a rich Logic App that I want to have no Integration Account linking as it is using no Integration Account features and when I give limited access to users to the Logic App but not the Integration Account, results in error:

Save logic app failed

> Failed to save logic app process-850. The client 'editest@...com'
>   with object id '14...9a' has permission to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/write' on scope
>   '/subscriptions/b54...ders/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/process-850';
>   however, it does not have permission to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/join/action' on the linked
>   scope(s)
>   '/subscriptions/b54...bc/resourceGroups/IntegrationAccounts/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/Free-EDI-Integration-Account'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that from the UI?

One way to do it is via the Azure Resource Explorer (https://resources.azure.com/)

[image: Azure Resource Explorer snapshot]

1. Go to the Resource Explorer
2. Search for your Logic App workflow,
3. Switch to (click on) Read/Write mode
4. Click edit
5. Delete the properties of the IntegrationAccount member, you should end up with something like `"integrationAccount": {}`
6. Call (click on) the PUT method.
7. Check on the Logic App UI, the Integration Account should be unlinked now :)

HTH